# LINE application login api auth2 not working

Tags: cordova, web-applications, oauth-2.0, line

I'm developing phonegap/cordova crossplatform app. And I'd like to login via LINE account.

I've followed instruction in https://developers.line.me/web-login/integrating-web-login which mean I've got ***channel_id, client_secret***, set ***callback_url*** (http://localhost)

I use link below to open login page from LINE application

https://access.line.me/dialog/oauth/weblogin?response_type=code&client_id=***channel_id***&redirect_uri=http://localhost&state=

after I press LOGIN button, it callback to https://access.line.me/dialog/oauth/authorize with text said: "Sorry, There were problems logging you in. Please wait a while before trying again." -- I've waited and tried again but it never work.

```
var lineapi = {
      authorize: function(options) {
          var deferred = $.Deferred();

          //Build the OAuth consent page URL
          //https://access.line.me/dialog/oauth/weblogin?response_type=code&client_id={Channel ID}&redirect_uri={Redirect URL}&state={State}
          var authUrl = 'https://access.line.me/dialog/oauth/weblogin?' + $.param({
              client_id: options.channel_id,
              redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
              response_type: 'code',
              // scope: options.scope,
              state: ''
          });

          //Open the OAuth consent page in the InAppBrowser
          var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');

          //The recommendation is to use the redirect_uri "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
          //which sets the authorization code in the browser's title. However, we can't
          //access the title of the InAppBrowser.
          //
          //Instead, we pass a bogus redirect_uri of "http://localhost", which means the
          //authorization code will get set in the url. We can access the url in the
          //loadstart and loadstop events. So if we bind the loadstart event, we can
          //find the authorization code and close the InAppBrowser after the user
          //has granted us access to their data.
          $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function(e) {
              console.log('loadstart:',e);
              var url = e.originalEvent.url;
              console.log("url:",url);
              var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
              var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);
              var callback = /\?callback=(.+)$/.exec(url);

              if (code || error) {
                  //Always close the browser when match is found
                  authWindow.close();
              }

              if (code) {
                  //Exchange the authorization code for an access token
                  console.log('calling oauth for accessToken');
                  $.post('https://api.line.me/v1/oauth/accessToken', {
                      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                      client_id: options.channel_id,
                      client_secret: options.channel_secret,
                      code: code,
                      redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri
                  }).done(function(data) {
                      alert(data);
                      deferred.resolve(data);
                  }).fail(function(response) {
                      alert(response);
                      deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
                  });
              } else if (error) {
                  //The user denied access to the app
                  console.log("error:",error);
                  deferred.reject({
                      error: error[1]
                  });
              }
          });

          return deferred.promise();
      }
  };

  $scope.loginLine = function(){

    lineapi.authorize({
        channel_id: ***my_channel_id***,
        channel_secret: ***my_channel_secret***,
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost',
        scope: 'PROFILE'
    });
  }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? 
Very appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on the resulting URL in the address line after you enter email/password credentials in the line login form - this should contain error message like this:

```
https://access.line.me/dialog/oauth/weblogin?response_type=code&forceSecondVerification=false&userId=XXX%40XXXXXX.com&client_id=XXXXXXXXX&showPermissionApproval=&displayType=b&idProvider=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2Fauth%2Fline%2Fcallback&state=&lang=&errorCode=400&errorMessage=AUTH_INVALID_REDIRECT_URL
```

In my example I have invalid redirect URL and error message `errorMessage=AUTH_INVALID_REDIRECT_URL`

As your oauth URL contains `localhost` as well I suppose your `errorMessage` will be the same.

The documentation [here](https://developers.line.me/web-login/integrating-web-login) says:

> The Redirect URL must match one of the URLs specified when registering your Channel. The comparison target is from the scheme to the path of the URL. The query parameter is not included as a comparison target. Specify a URL encoded string to specify the query parameter value.